# AngularJs 'md-sidenav' not responding to click listener on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, firefox

I am currently working on angular project. The app has a sidenav according to specifications of angularjs material design. When I click on the menu icon controlling the sidenav on chrome and other major browers, it works but it does not work on firefox. Please visit the link below with chrome and firefox to test the sample app on plunker.
[Here is the link](https://plnkr.co/edit/PuLaiSFoIhDcNu73vk60?p=preview)

```
  <body layout="column" ng-controller="sidenavController as vm">
    <md-toolbar layout="row">
      <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="menu">
         <md-icon md-svg-src="menu" ng-click="vm.togglelist()"></md-icon>
      </md-button>
      <span style="padding-top:5px;">AngularJs Toolbar</span>
    </md-toolbar>
    <div layout="row" flex>
      <md-sidenav md-is-locked-open="$mdMedia('gt-sm')" class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2" md-component-id="left">sidenav</md-sidenav>
      <md-content flex>content</md-content>
    </div>

      <!-- AngularJS Material Dependencies -->
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.11/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.11/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.11/angular-aria.min.js"></script>

    <!-- AngularJS Material Javascript  -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.4/angular-material.min.js"></script>
     <script src="script.js"></script>
     <script src="controllers.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Please, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have `ng-click="vm.togglelist()"` on `md-button` & not on md-icon.

```
<md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="menu" ng-click="vm.togglelist()">
    <md-icon md-svg-src="menu"></md-icon>
</md-button>
```

[**Working plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/4OoXR1fJDSfz4WBGrwcv?p=preview)

Comment: Oh, thank you very much @Shantanu. My problem is solved with this your solution.....Very grateful. You have saved the trouble of trying to identify this problem for the rest of the day. I would have up voted your answer but unfortunately, my reputation on stackoverflow is low to do that.